# stylus mixin with &:nth-of-type

Tags: stylus

I would like something like this

```
number(x)
    &:nth-of-type(x)
```

*Mostly just for readability - and for a basic example of when I might need to use the & in a mixin...*

```
li //
    number(1)
        color: red
    number(2)
        color: blue
```

To yield...

```
li //
    &:nth-of-type(1)
        color: red
    &:nth-of-type(2)
        color: blue
```

Is this possible? Escaping ... ? ? ?

for my break-points... i use a variable --- but can't here

`@media break-point-1` etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old question and I am sure you found a solution a long time ago but there isn´t an accepted answer and maybe is useful for other users.

To use variables in selectors, they must be enclosed in braces ([interpolation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html)). To get the content in the mixin, use the [block mixin](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/mixins.html#block-mixins) feature:

**Stylus**

```
number(x)
  &:nth-of-type({x})
    {block}

li
  +number(1)
    color red
  +number(2)
    color blue
```

**CSS:**

```
li:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: #f00;
}
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  color: #00f;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @blonfu. I had just heard about this `+` on a podcast. https://syntax.fm/show/003/css-preprocessors-and-structuring-css

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you can create shortcut like that

But you can use this mixin

```
setColors(colorList) 
  for col, index in colorList 
         &:nth-child({index}) 
             color: col;

setColors(red blue);
```